# What are my options for implementing a virtual credits system for a Mac app?

Tags: ios, security, in-app-purchase

I'm building an app which I intend to distribute through the Mac App Store. I will use in-app purchases to allow users to buy "credits" which they can consume in the app. I will use Apple's IAP APIs to handle the money transaction side of things, but I'm wondering how I best go about securely storing the current balance of credits.

Obviously, I'd like to avoid "clever" users from messing with my app's files on disk to increase the number of credits, so at the very least I need to encrypt this file. But even that is not sufficient, because a user could simply restore from a backup copy to restore their credit balance.

One obvious option is to run my own webserver and have the app connect to that for every transaction, but that sounds cumbersome. I've looked for virtual currency services for iOS (since this is much more common in iOS apps), but most (all?) of them have some cross-marketing angle to them, forcing me to put ads in my app which I don't want. I will gladly pay for a service with a simple API as long as it's completely transparant to my users. E.g. I don't want my users to have to sign up for an account on some 3rd party's website.

What are my options here? Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you actually want any real security, you need to use a server.

No matter what kind of cryptography you do client side, users can always reset the state of the app and then add the receipt for IAP that you will then validate. In short, they can always erase the phones memory that they consumed those credits.

If what they are purchasing is only in the app(i.e. its just programaticly unlocked functionality) and is not provided by an outside server/ service, then a sufficiently motivated user( likely with a jailbroken phone) could simply tweak your code to provide that functionality. So you can't have real security in that case. Your best bet is just obfuscation.